# Fail to convert LINQ query result to ToList

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Get All Countries 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<CountryVM> GetAllCountry( )
        {
            using (Context context  = new Context() )
            {
                var countries = context.COUNTRY.Select(c => new CountryVM()
                     {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         DESCRIPTION = c.DESCRIPTION,
                     }

                ).ToList(); // Gets Exception here.
                return countries;
            }
```

Why am I not able to convert to ToList() ?

Iget following Exception :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LANGUAGE]
>   ToList[LANGUAGE](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LANGUAGE])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Are you referencing `System.Linq` ?

Comment: yes I am referencing to System.Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common error, and since you may encounter it multiple times, please let me explain why is this happening.

Let's read the error message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Linq to entities, the library translating linq expressions to SQL (assuming you're using a SQLServer database), doesn't understand something you're asking it to do. What is it it doesn't get?

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[LANGUAGE]
>   ToList[LANGUAGE] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[LANGUAGE])' method

It's quite a long and messy signature because of the namespace and the return type we're not used to see like this, but it is the method you asked Linq2Entities to translate: ToList<LANGUAGE>(IEnumerable<LANGUAGE>) which returns a List<LANGUAGE>. You probably called the extension method .ToList() on a `EntityCollection<LANGUAGE>` somewhere.

> and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

There, it said it, it can't translate your Linq expression to a store (read: SQL) expression.

Why is Linq2Entities trying to translate your `EntityCollection<LANGUAGE>.ToList()` to SQL ? Because everything in the lambda expression (the `x => do some stuff` part) will be translated to SQL. Since nowhere in the shown code is there any mention of a EntityCollection<LANGUAGE>, I'd have to guess it's in the `CountryVM`'s constructor.

And that's why Zunair Zubair's answers works: your .Select(), and therefore your lambda expression, isn't translated by Linq2Entities, because you're calling it on an object, so there's no SQL involved, thus no translation problem.

**SOLUTION**

It's hard to advise anything since I don't know what are you trying to achieve in the constructor, but a possible solution would be :

```
using (Context context = new Context() )
{
    List<LANGUAGE> langs = context.LANGUAGE.ToList();
    return context.COUNTRY.Select(c => new CountryVM(langs)
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        DESCRIPTION = c.DESCRIPTION,
    }).ToList();
}
```

and remove the hypothetical `context.LANGUAGE.ToList();` from this second constructor. This involves two requests to the database and could be optimized further, but not without knowing your intent and table foreign keys.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask you is that Is it necessary to create View Model classes if I am using EF because EF already generates all the required Model classes. Can I use those classes to fetch data from database using LINQ and display them. I am told that I need to create View Model class to send data from DAL to Controller and then to view. -Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert on MVC nor MVVM, but classes generated by EF should be only accessible to your DAL/Model, and your Model classes should provide classes that more or less mirror those EF classes. This will allow you to more easily customize them (ie you'll probably want to make them Serializable at some point, since WebServices are everywhere these days)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the expression

`context.COUNTRY.Select(c => new CountryVM()
                     {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         DESCRIPTION = c.DESCRIPTION,
                     })`

is returning a single entity instead of an enumerable, which is why it cannot be converted to a list.

Comment: No it is not returning single Entity

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following

```
var countries = context.COUNTRY.ToList().Select(c => new CountryVM()
                 {
                     ...
                 }

            ).ToList();
            return countries;
```

Comment: Casting `ToList()` before won't solve the problem, and contributes nothing, since `Select` returns `IEnumerable` anyway.

Comment: ToList() (or any other method that will execute an IQueryable) is called first that brings the Users data into .NET memory, with the subsequent Convert option done afterwards.

Comment: Even if it did work, that's no way to write code. Fixing the symptom instead of the problem is almost always bad practice.

Comment: @OmriAharon I must disagree with you. Without the first `.ToList()` it uses `Queryable.Select(Expression<Func<T,TRet>>)` whilst WITH the `.ToList()` if uses `Enumerable.Select(Func<T,TRet>)`

Comment: @Aron Accepted, but still shouldn't be used as a solution :)

Comment: sorry it works by first converting to list and then doing select. But the possible drawback of it is that it will fetch all the data from DB which I think is a big overhead. IS there any other way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @Anand see if this helps you understand the problem
[link](http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/c/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-xxx-method-and-this-method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: This answer, while effective, should warn about its drawbacks, namely a potential loss in performance since it retrieves every single column of the COUNTRY table, when only DESCRIPTION and ID are needed.

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't this work, assuming your c.ID and c.DESCRIPTION are scalar properties..

```
var countries = (from c in context.COUNTRY
                 select new CountryVM()
                 {
                     ID = c.ID,
                     DESCRIPTION = c.DESCRIPTION,
                 }).ToList();
```